# How to read and write two lines of string in MIPS?

Tags: file, mips

I need to read two lines of string from file `Input.txt` as

```
15/02/1996
25/05/1332
```

and I don't know how to read the second string in the new line.
I tried many ways and read lots of documents but I can't solve this.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

## Khai bao

.data
    fi: .asciiz "input.txt" 
    fo: .asciiz "output.txt"
    buffer1: .space 11
    buffer2: .space 10
.text

## Open

```
li $v0, 13  
la $a0, fi  #a0 = file name
li $a1, 0   #a1 = 0 (0: read, 1: write)
li $a2, 0   #a2 = 0 (0: ignore mode)
syscall
move $t1, $v0
```

## Read data

```
li $v0, 14  
move $a0, $t1   
la $a1, buffer1 
li $a2, 11  
la $a1, buffer2
li $a2, 10
syscall
```

## Close

```
li $v0, 16  # close file
move $a0, $t0   
syscall
```

Comment: I found solution for this problem. Thanks so much.